# drive geometry error with vfat

Tags: rhel, lvm, vfat

I'm curious what this error means:

```
[root@server1 ~]# mkfs -t vfat /dev/example
mkfs.fat 3.0.20 (12 Jun 2013)
unable to get drive geometry, using default 255/63
```

I was attempting to make a file system after creating a logical volume.

The error doesn't seem to interfere with anything in the example I'm working through in my book, I would just like to know what that type of error means! Is this specific to vfat?

Comment: What is `/dev/example`?  Is it a regular file or just a nickname you gave to an actual device file?

Comment: /dev/example is just the example path. The exercise has us create a physical device path called /dev/Accounting/finance.

Comment: You don't answer if it's a real device or just a regular file which would explain the warning you got!

Comment: Well this is a new subject to me so I'm still learning. What I'm trying to do is create a file system for logical volume on a physical device.

Where is it trying to get "drive geometry" from and what does that even mean? What is the default 255/63 it is using?

Comment: It should normally be able to detect a hard drive's geometry (physical specs) but usually gives that warning when you try to create a filesystem on a file instead of a device.  If you do it on an actual device, the only advantage you may have in hiding it is wasting people's time when they want to help you.  When you need help with a command that gives an error, you should give the exact command you typed in.